# How to setup initial position of target element in anime.js?

Tags: vue.js, anime.js

### Target

[image]

On click "Open menu" button:

1. Dim overlay appearing with fade-in animation

[image]

2. Once dim overlay animation done, from the top, dim overlay is appearing with the sliding animation from the top to bottom:

[image]

### Solution attempt and problem

```xml
<template>
  <transition @enter="animateOpening" @leave="animateClosing">
    <div 
      class="SearchProductsPane-DimUnderlay"
      v-if="isOpen"
      :ref="elementsReferencesIDs.overlay"
     >
        <div 
          class="SearchProductsPane-Body" 
         :ref="elementsReferencesIDs.body"
       >
         <!-- ... -->
       </div>
    </div>
  </transition>
</template>
```

```js
import { Vue, Component } from "vue-property-decorator";
import Animation from "animejs";

@Component
export default class SearchProductsPane extends Vue {

  private elementsReferencesIDs: Record<"overlay" | "body", string> = {
    overlay: "Overlay", body: "Body"
  };

  private animateOpening(_element: Element, done: () => {}): void {
    Animation
      .timeline({
        easing: "linear",
        duration: 500,
        complete: done
      })
      .add({
        targets: this.$refs[this.elementsReferencesIDs.overlay],
        opacity: [0, 1]
      })
      .add({
        targets: this.$refs[this.elementsReferencesIDs.body],
        translateY: "100%"
      })
  }

  private animateClosing(): void {

  }
}
```

With current solution, the `.SearchProductsPane-Body` will move from the normal position to the downward outside of the screen. Instead of it, I need it move from the upward outside of the screen to it normal position.

I tried reach it by adding of below class:

```css
.SearchProductsPane-Body__InitialPosition {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

However, the `animejs` animation starts from the `0%`, not `-100%`. How to change it?

Comment: The animejs can set start and end value. See https://animejs.com/documentation/#fromToValues

Comment: @User28, thank you for the comment answer. Please add the regular (non-comment) answer, and I'll give you the reputation prize ASAP.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I can't write a full answer. As I am still not 100% understandable for the question, so you may write an answer for someone else who may have the same problem.

Comment: @User28, copy-paste of your first comment and code from documentation will be enough, because I solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `From Value` in animeJs, which allows you to define you'r animation origin:

```
anime.stagger(100, {from: 'center'})
```

you'r options are:

1. first: animation starts from the first element(Default from value)
2. last: animation starts from the last element
3. center: animation starts from the center
4. index: you choose which element the animation starts from

here is the [docs](https://animejs.com/documentation/#staggeringFrom).

Or you can use `From to` which forces the animation to start at a specified value.

In you'r code:

```
anime({
  targets: '.SearchProductsPane-DimUnderlay'
});
```

docs [here](https://animejs.com/documentation/#fromToValues)